# How to fetch data from document library in SPFX react within a very short period of time?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, sharepoint-library, react-webpart

I am fetching data from document library which has more than 5000 items. While doing this, it takes lots of time. Is there any solution to reduce this time?

Comment: how many items are you fetching at a time? Use PnP JS library, use indexing on columns if using filters in API call

Comment: currently I'm fetching more than 4000 data but after some time it can be much more than that and using spHttpClient for fetching data.